# Angular когда начинает действовать?

Tags: angularjs

Правильно ли я понимаю, что Angular "после загрузки страницы"! начинает парсить все элементы, а потом запускает digest?

Comment: что имеется ввиду под _начинает парсить все элементы, а потом запускает digest_?

Comment: @Grundy загрузилась страница полностью -> angular обходит всю стрницу (парсит элементы), а потом запускает digest цикл (watcherы)

Comment: [вот здесь есть описание небольшое](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler)

Comment: _angular обходит всю стрницу (парсит элементы), а потом запускает digest цикл (watcherы)_ Не совсем, ангуляр не обходит всю страницу. Он выбирает только те элементы которые у него в списке директив/компонент

Comment: @Grundy а как он узнает какие элементы у него в списке?

Comment: во-первых, в стандартном модуле описаны стандартные директивы, во-вторых, в пользовательских модулях могут быть описаны свои директивы

Comment: все начинается [отсюда](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/beab3baec3728cd4034df4bbccdf52af2b7d8b64/src/angular.suffix) и вызова функции [angularInit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L1645)

Comment: @Grundy Как ангуляр может знать watcherы не пройдясь по всем элементам спарсив их данные? То есть он я так понимаю по окончанию загрузки страницы проходит по всем элементам...

Comment: я дал ссылки откуда начинать смотреть, просто посмотри что он на самом деле делает.

Answer (score 1):

Основная работа начинается с вызова [функции angularInit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L1649)

```
jqLite(function() {
    angularInit(window.document, bootstrap);
});
```

Основная цель данной функции найти элемент помеченный одним из допустимых атрибутов `ng-app` и, если разрешено автоматическое разворачивание приложения, вызвать [функцию `bootstrap`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L1742) передав найденный элемент в качестве корневого.

Внутри запускается [функция boBootstrap](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L1748) создающая [`injector`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L1773) и вызывающая

```
injector.invoke(['$rootScope', '$rootElement', '$compile', '$injector',
   function bootstrapApply(scope, element, compile, injector) {
    scope.$apply(function() {
      element.data('$injector', injector);
      compile(element)(scope);
    });
  }]
);
```

Таким образом *сначала* запускается [функция `compile`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L972), которая на самом деле является сервисом ангуляра: [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Внутри нее осуществляется проход по всем узлам находящимся внутри выбранного корневого элемента. Конкретно этим занимается [функция compileNodes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L1951).